# Camera 2 - App will minimizing when calling "openCamera" method in Camera 2 API

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, android-camera2

I am developing a camera application using latest Camera 2 API, and I have a button in my app to choose front facing camera and back facing camera on each button click.

Code for that is:

```
switch_camera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // facing = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING);
        if (facing != null && facing == CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_FRONT) {
            //isfrontcam=true;
            try {
                manager.openCamera("0",mStateCallback,mBackgroundHandler);
            } catch (SecurityException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else if (facing != null && facing == CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_BACK) {
            // isfrontcam = true;
            try {
                manager.openCamera("1", mStateCallback, mBackgroundHandler);
            } catch (SecurityException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is  app will minimizing automatically when I click the button to select camera.The above snippet is executing on button click. I could not understand the reason for this bug. Can anyone help?

Comment: it would help if you told us what the error is as well?

Comment: are you sure you are using it for android >= 21

Comment: no errors in logcat , the  app will exit after calling " manager.openCamera " method

Comment: How about in AndroidMonitor? right when the app closes there should be a big block of red lines, usually if you scroll to the start of that you'd get a good idea of what happened from the first lines.

Comment: @ankit aggarwal : Yes I am using lollipop device :) >=21 , Actually app is minimizing, not crashing and other errors

Comment: What is minimizing? You said `it will exit`. So please be clear.

Comment: I am sorry for that, App will not exit app will minimize automatically when executing the above snippet

Answer (score 0):

Need logcat info to understand your actual issue, with out having much information i guess the below solution might work for you.

Instead of -->  manager.openCamera("0",mStateCallback,mBackgroundHandler);
& manager.openCamera("1", mStateCallback, mBackgroundHandler);

Try: 
manager.openCamera(getBackFacingCameraId(cManager),
             mStateCallback,mBackgroundHandler);

manager.openCamera(getFrontFacingCameraId(cManager),mStateCallback,
             mBackgroundHandler);

```
String getFrontFacingCameraId(CameraManager cManager){
   for(final String cameraId : cManager.getCameraIdList()){
         CameraCharacteristics characteristics =     
         cManager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId);
         int cOrientation =        
         characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING);
         if(cOrientation == CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_FRONT)      
             return cameraId;
         }
         return null;
}


String getBackFacingCameraId(CameraManager cManager){
     for(final String cameraId : cManager.getCameraIdList()){
         CameraCharacteristics characteristics =      
         cManager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId);
         int cOrientation =   
         characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING);
         if(cOrientation == CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_BACK)   
            return cameraId;
         }
         return null;
}
```

Ref : https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Camera2/+/f5e51ec44934d6d687267d2aff6386f5b728dd9f/src/com/android/camera/one/v2/OneCameraManagerImpl.java

Comment: Hai Thanks to spent time for my question ,I have tried with this snippet ,but still problem is not solved .